# I Would Like to Add a Line to a Table Plot with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am plotting data with pgfplots. I would like to add a line to this plot. My code is as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot table {
0   90
1   72
2   57
24  -43
25  -26
26  0
27  0
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I tried to add a line with its plot coordinates, to no avail

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot table {
0   90
1   72
2   57
24  -43
25  -26
26  0
27  0
};
\end{axis}

\draw [dashed] (24, -50) -- (24,60);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I add this line ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just add this line with `\addplot`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table {
0   90
1   72
2   57
24  -43
25  -26
26  0
27  0
};
\addplot[dashed] coordinates {(24, -50) (24,60)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The reason is pgfplots having different (implicitly and automatically) scaling. You may draw with plain TikZ to get explicit scaling.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2mm,y=.4mm]
\def\datapoints{
    (0,90) (1,72) (2,57) (24,-43) (25,-26) (26,0) (27,0)}

\draw[densely dotted] (24,-50)--(24,60);

\draw[blue,mark=ball] plot coordinates{\datapoints};

\foreach \i in {0,5,...,25}
\draw[gray] (\i,-55) node[below,black]{$\i$}--+(90:1.5mm);
\foreach \j in {-50,0,50,100}
\draw[gray] (-3,\j) node[left,black]{$\j$}--+(0:1.5mm);
\draw (-3,-55) rectangle (30,105);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two options. Either you use a reasonably new compatibility mode (1.11 or higher) or preprend the coordinates with `axis cs:`. I illustrate the first option. Compared to using `\addplot` his has the advantage that you can use all the usual constructions like, say, `bend left`, you do not have problems with legends and so on.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot table {
0   90
1   72
2   57
24  -43
25  -26
26  0
27  0
};
\draw [dashed] (24, -50) -- (24,60);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]